# Typed DataSets in WebApplication Projects

Tags: asp.net, xsd, strongly-typed-dataset, vs-web-application-project

I am converting an older C# **Website Project** into a **Web Application Project** so that we can better manage it in our source control system. I have run into a problem.

The Website Project used strongly-typed-datasets (i.e. .XSD files). There is C# code written that uses these strongly typed datasets as an object. That worked fine when it was a Website Project but does NOT compile now that it is a Web Application project. The compiler can not find the reference to the datas set because datasets are not compiled.

Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use XSD.exe on the command line to generate the dataset classes into a class file and add the file to the new project.

```
xsd.exe StronglyTypedDataset.xsd /dataset
```

This will generate the file "StronglyTypedDataset.cs".  Use the `/namespace:My.Project.Namespace` flag if you need to put the dataset classes into a specific namespace.

This is essentially what's going on behind the scenes in your website project.

Comment: I guess that Visual Studio stopped shipping with XSD.exe. Had to download it but it worked.

Comment: Depends which version of Studio you have.  XSD.exe is actually part of the Microsoft .Net SDK, which installs with paid versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice guide to integrate XSD compiler into Visual Studio (2003 - 2010). It might help you automate the process: http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/Using_XSD_with_Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010_.2810.0.29

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that worked for me when converting into a Web Application Project was to remove the .xsd file from the project and include it again.

VS 2008 automatically defined the "Custom Tool" property to use (MSDataSetGenerator) and re-creates the *.designer.cs file for me every time the xsd change.